How do I programmatically find iTunes status on Windows?
On a Mac, I can find out what track iTunes is playing, and even what playlist it's in, so I know what's coming up. I'm using Perl and executing AppleScript commands.
Is there a way to do the same thing on iTunes for Windows?
